# Drawing editable text in Win2D?

Tags: c#, graphics, textbox, uwp, win2d

**Is there any easy way to implement editable text field in Win2D?**

I'm trying to make a simple text tool, which would add text over image (just like in `MS Paint`).

[image]

By clicking inside the text's boundaries, it'd make that text ´selected`. Selected text would draw lines around it's area according to it's boundary box, and start blinking a caret in the clicked position. By clicking elsewhere, it'd unselect the text (hides possible caret, text selection and boundary box).

I was thinking about a simple solution with `XAML TextBox`, but I'm afraid that it doesn't support all of the effects that `Win2D` does (f.ex warping the text).

What would be the correct way to do it?

Comment: In the paint app, if the text box lose focus, the text will not be editable. So I think may be you can use the `Textbox` and after text confirmed, draw the text to the canvas for effects dealing.

Comment: I've been rolling this problem in my head, and I think the only solution is to create my own `custom control`, which works partly like normal `TextBox`. Warping and other effects make the problem harder. Basically I could only override the implementation of `caret`, `outline` and `text selection` (+ few other things) for the `TextBox`. I'd then draw this control over the text, and drawn the caret, outlines and possible text selection over it (with transparency). I think I'll just need to test and try different ideas. But `custom control`s are a step forward...